# Move Google Calendar delegates under Google Calendar in Calendar.app

Tags: calendar, osx-mountain-lion, google-calendar, calendar.app

I'm using Calendar on OS X Mountain Lion. Everything is updated.

**Problem:**  Is there any way to make it so that each delegate shows up under `calendar.google.com`, this would be ideal.

Or if they could just display Person, Personal Work, etc... without the little drop down arrow?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is how Calendar interprets GCal delegates. You can collapse drop-down menu and the problem is "fixed", don't care about that tiny arrow. ;)

Answer (score 1):

By default it will only show your primary calendar.  You can enable additional calendars by enabling them in your [Google Sync Settings](https://www.google.com/calendar/syncselect).  Simply enable them and save.  Next time your calendar program syncs, it will show the newly enabled calendars.

Once you have enabled the additional calendars, go into your Calendar app preferences and turn off the delegate calendars or else you will have duplicate entries.